# OpenAPI Swagger Java Not able to get value inside Example value

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger, openapi

In my post request body getting null value. Not able to get default json value.
My code :

```
@Operation(summary = "pushAdjustmentList")
    @PostMapping(value = "/push/adjList")
    public ResponseEntity<String> pushAdjustmentList(
            @RequestBody(description = "List of Adjustment Ids",required = true) List<Long> adjList) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        String response = null;
        log.debug("Adjustments list submitted : {}",adjList);
        try {
            response = producerService.pushAdjustmentList(adjList);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            log.error(LOGGER_COULD_NOT_PROCESS_REQUEST,ex.getMessage());
            response = ex.getMessage();
            status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(response);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using springdoc-openapi-ui you can use the following solution:

```
    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(
        content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Long.class))),
        description = "Request with list of Long"
    )
```

And if you are using spring-fox here you can know how to migrate to springdoc:
https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

Comment: I tried this way also and other way also still getting null value, dont know what is the issue                                                                  @Operation(summary = "pushAdjustmentList")
 @PostMapping(value = "/push/adjList")
 public ResponseEntity<String> pushAdjustmentList(
   @RequestBody(content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Long.class))),description = "List of Adjustment Ids") @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody List<Long> adjList) {
  ----
 }

Comment: Check that you are using right annotation from io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters. And check that you are using actually springdoc-openapi-ui, not springfox

Comment: @Anton..Using right annotation. In schema example is null coming.                                   [example: null                                                                                                                         String                                                                                                                                  example: null]

Comment: I am able to solve my problem by downgarding dependency in pom from jackson-databind.version- 2.14.0 to 2.13.4.2